# how to restrict jquery date picker to only current month?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to set the date-picker to show only the current month and user cannot move to previous months or next months.Is there any in build function for it?

Comment: which jquery plugin are you using??

Comment: I found this and it solve my problem                                 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({stepMonths: 0 });

After that it prevents going to next and previous months

Answer (score 8):

Use datapiker so:

```
// temp vars used below
var currentTime = new Date() 
var minDate = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth(), +1); //one day next before month
var maxDate =  new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth() +2, +0); // one day before next month
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
minDate: minDate, 
maxDate: maxDate 
});
```

Documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: than you,but using this it only prevent next months for me

Comment: set option `changeMonth: false,` ;)

Comment: This is actually not correct. The maxDate must be `new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth() +1, 0)` like the others already said

Comment: Best thing about it is even if you add currentTime.getDate()+30 on January 30, it will return march 1 or march 2, without returning Invalid date error.
I Know Iam late into this.

Answer (score 6):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    // Add this line

    stepMonths: 0,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`min-max` range date](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) from datepicker

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
```

Or just some configurations

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    stepMonths: false,
    dateFormat: 'dd MM'
});
```

To change the month just add the `defaultDate: '2m'` with the number of month that you want to add (or add a minus like `'-2m'` to remove).

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nymos/pXVTP/) with the working code

Answer (score 2):

Use the options [`minDate` and `maxDate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate).

You can get the `minDate` and `maxDate` with this

```
function getMinMaxCurrentDate() {
   var d = new Date();
   var day = d.getDate();         // range 1-31
   var month = d.getMonth() + 1;  // range 1-12
   var year = d.getFullYear();    // ie. (2011)
   var max;

   if (month <= 7) {
      if (month == 2) {
         // check for leap years for Febuary
         var isLeap = new Date(year,1,29).getDate() == 29;
         max = 28 + (isLeap ? 1 : 0);
      } else {
         max = (month & 1) ? 31 : 30;
      }
   } else {
      max = (month & 1) ? 30 : 31;
   }

   return [-day, max - day];

}

var minMax = getMinMaxCurrentDate();
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: minMax[0], maxDate: minMax[1] });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `changeMonth:false` and `stepMonths:0` and it will work.

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    stepMonths: 0, 
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    firstDay: 1,
}).datepicker("setDate", "+0d" );
```

Working fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/scottcwilson/phkkt20e/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
// temp vars used below
var date = new Date();


// get the current date
var minDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+ testMounth, 1);
var maxDate =  new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() +1 +testMounth, -0);

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
minDate: minDate,
maxDate: maxDate
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using jQuery UI Datepicker, this would work:

```
function getDaysInMonth(y,m){
    return (new Date(y,m,0)).getDate() + 1;
}

var td= new Date();
var minDate = new Date( td.getYear(), td.getMonth(), +1, +getDaysInMonth( td.getYear(), td.getMonth() ) );
var maxDate = new Date( td.getYear(), td.getMonth(), +1, 0);

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate 
});
```

Comment: I think there is a typo here in the minDate and maxDate algorithm. For instance the maxDate should be `var maxDate = new Date( td.getYear(), td.getMonth()+1, 0);` and not `var maxDate = new Date( td.getYear(), td.getMonth(), +1, 0);`