# Display only one month date on selection of start date in datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a problem in my project. I want to show only one month date on select my start date, Say I select February 1st then the end date will be February 28, User could not select higher than 28 February, But don't know how to do this.
Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

$("#checkin").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true
})
.on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $("#checkout").datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        minDate: ev.date.setDate(ev.date + 30)
    });
});
```

Comment: you should read the documentation of your datepicker

Comment: Are you using jquery ui datepicker?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap datepicker

Answer (score 0):

To disable any date selection past mindate and maxdate, you can use :

```
$( "#checkin" ).datepicker({ 
    minDate: minDate, 
    maxDate: maxDate 
});
```

In your case its month's start and end date so :

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var minDate = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth(), 1);
var maxDate =  new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth() + 1, 0);
$( "#checkin" ).datepicker({ 
    minDate: minDate, 
    maxDate: maxDate 
});
```

If you want to have it based on user selection:

```
$("#checkin").datepicker({
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function(ev){

    var selected = new Date(ev.format());
    var minDate = new Date(selected.getFullYear(), selected.getMonth(), 1);
    var maxDate =  new Date(selected.getFullYear(), selected.getMonth() + 1, 0);
     $('#checkout').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
     $('#checkout').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);
});
```

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409838/how-to-restrict-jquery-date-picker-to-only-current-month) for more.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6krs3awp/8/) I created for this example.

Comment: My checkin date should not be fixed, All i want that the checkout date is one month based on my checkin date

Comment: I am not getting any erro but the checkout date is not showing as specified

Comment: Also you can try `change` instead of `option`

Comment: After replacing your code It shown date As March 23, I am added format in option value but without any success

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI Datepicker, then this code should work fine for you:

```
$("#checkin").datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        onSelect: function(ev) {
            var fromDate = $('#checkin').datepicker("getDate");
            var rangemindate = new Date(fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth(),fromDate.getDate() + 1);
            var rangemaxdate = new Date(fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth(),fromDate.getDate() + 30); 
            $("#checkout").datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
                minDate: rangemindate,
                maxDate: rangemaxdate
            });
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps you.